# Moss on siding, do I need to replace this siding before painting?

Tags: siding, moss

This part of my house has a bit of moss, it looks like it has damaged the siding. I'd like to paint the front of the house, but I want to deal with the moss first. Will I need to replace the siding or can I just clear up the moss and paint over it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the siding, but kill the moss off first with a product you can get at the big box stores. Many products claim it will keep a roof clear of moss for 2 years. It will take a few weeks after applying it for it to do its job. Do not power wash or scrub the roof!! After it is gone remove the loose paint, making certain the wall is clean before priming and finish painting.